# How do I figure out what activity is responsible for a fragment?

Tags: android

I have a file `fragment_item_attachment.xml` which has a `<RelativeLayout>` and a corresponding `ItemAttachmentFragment.java`, but how do I figure out what the corresponding activity is? The activities all seem too to be named differently.

Comment: Well from what you mentioned there's supposed to be only one fragment, so what makes it so confusing? The Activity which calls the fragment is the Activity, or are you trying to programatically get the activity name from fragment?

Comment: @Superman The project has dozens of fragments and dozens of activities. I want to know how I can figure out which activity invokes a fragment so I can pass configuration options to the fragment.

Comment: Well, then as @Charlie mentioned in the answer, you'll have to look for em manually. And you just only mentioned Fragment, Fragments can be customized to a great extent, and how many activities and fragments to be precise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which Activity starts the Fragment.

In order to have added the fragment, it's likely you some code similar to:

```
// Here we have the fragment, but it isn't bound to an activity.
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();

// Here the fragment will be bound to the activity.
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
```

Once the fragment is bound to the activity, the fragment's getActivity() method will return the activity.

If it isn't bound to an activity, getActivity() will return null.

If you started the fragment from the MainActivity, and you want to access a method in that activity, you could write the following in the fragment:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).myCustomMethod();
```

To write safer code, avoiding a possible NullPointerException or ClassCastException if the fragment is used in a different way:

```
if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).myCustomMethod();
}
```